# How do I query a list of entities in a many to many relationship in JPA?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Suppose I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manifest")
public class Manifest extends DbTable implements Serializable {
    public Manifest() { }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="manifests",fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
    public List<Thingy> thingys;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="thingy")
public class Thingy extends DbTable implements Serializable {
    public Thingy(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "manifest_thingy",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "thingy_id", referencedColumnName="id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "manifest_id", referencedColumnName="id"))
    public List<Manifest> manifests;
}
```

How can I query my thingies that belong to a given manifest? I have tried queries like

```
"SELECT DISTINCT d 
 FROM Thingy d
 WHERE :manifest MEMBER OF d.manifests"
```

or

```
"SELECT DISTINCT d
 FROM Thingy d
 JOIN d.manifests m
 WHERE m = :manifest"
```

or

```
"SELECT DISTINCT d
 FROM Thingy d
 JOIN d.manifests m
 WHERE m.id = :manifestId"
```

the latter of those three being basically the only suggestion I could find searching around for this, but to no avail. For all 3 of those I think what I'm getting is an empty list (rather than an error). The query is being fed through something like this (parameters set as appropriate):

```
myEntityManager
    .createQuery(giantQueryStringGoesHere, Thingy.class)
    .setParameter("manifest", myManifestObject)
    .getResultList();
```

Comment: Ok uh whoops, actually the third query works fine (and probably the second one too), I just had my database set up incorrectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the specific manifest ID couldn't you just retrieve that manifest and get the list of thingys from it?

```
Manifest m = em.find(Manifest.class, manifestId);
List<Thingy> thingys = m.thingys;
```

Comment: Oh yeah that totally works too. I wanted to set it up in a typed query so I wouldn't be loading the other stuff into memory, and also so additional filtering on the query I'd be doing (not shown in OP) would be done in the database.